# Updating of cells in jqgrid with backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jqgrid

Is it possible to assign and id to td element and get access to this element by this id and change the value?

Can it brake all jqgrid object?

I have backbone model, called sensorModel, and sensorCollection, and on value:changed i have call callback function in tableView:

```
 changeGridValue: function(model) {
        var id = model.get('id');
        console.log(model.get('value'));
        console.log(model);
        this.container.find('table').jqGrid('setCell', 1, id, model.get('value') + " " + model.get('unit'));

        this.reloadView();
        //this.jqgridElem.setCell();
```

},

But the problem is that if i want to put value in cell i have to know index of row, but this index is stored in my collection.

So is it possible to pass in parameter both collection and model with changed value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but looks like you want to "submit" your form in signInView using viewA or viewB (eg. loginPage and loginDropDown). Am I right?

```
define(["jquery" ,
    "underscore" ,
    "backbone" ,
    "viewA",
    "viewB",
    //the others file
    ],function($ , _ , Backbone, viewA, viewB){

    var signInView = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function() {
        // listen to viewA and viewB and fire signIn action in this view
        this.listenTo(this.viewA, "signIn", this.signIn);
        this.listenTo(this.viewB, "signIn", this.signIn);
      },
      events : {
        'click #signInBtn' : 'signIn'
      },
      signIn : function(youCanPassYourFormModelHere){
        this.trigger("signIn");
      }
    });
    return viewB;
});
```

Your modified code (added triggers):

```
define(["jquery" ,
    "underscore" ,
    "backbone" ,
    "text!templates/Layout/signIn.html"
    //the others file
    ],function($ , _ , Backbone, SignIn){

    var viewA = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function() {

      },
      events : {
       'click #signInBtn' : 'signIn'
      },
      signIn : function(){
       this.trigger("signIn", formModel);
      }
    });
    return viewA;
});


define(["jquery" ,
    "underscore" ,
    "backbone" ,
    "text!templates/Layout/signIn.html"
    //the others file
    ],function($ , _ , Backbone, SignIn){

    var viewB = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function() {

      },
      events : {
       'click #signInBtn' : 'signIn'
      },
      signIn : function(){
       this.trigger("signIn", formModel);
      }
    });
    return viewB;
});
```